# Como carregar todas as .lib em um diretório através do CMake?

Tags: importação, cmake

Tenho em meu `CMakeLists.txt` varias chamadas para o `add_library` onde essas chamadas de bibliotecas(.lib) estão localizadas em um mesmo diretório. Gostaria de importar todas as libs desse diretório `/lib` sem ter que usar o `add_library` e `set_target_properties` para cada uma delas.

CMakeLists:

```
add_library(avcodec STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(avcodec PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../lib/ffmpeg/lib/avcodec.lib")

add_library(avformat STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(avformat PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../lib/ffmpeg/lib/avformat.lib")

add_library(avutil STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(avutil PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../lib/ffmpeg/lib/avutil.lib")

include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../lib/ffmpeg/include")

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -static -lstdc++ -lwinpthread -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS") 

add_executable(appffmpeg)
target_link_libraries(appffmpeg curl avcodec avformat avutil)
```

Existe alguma forma mais eficiente de se fazer isso?

Como eu faria caso quisesse importar todas as libs e deixar algumas de fora, exemplo, não importar `postproc.lib` e `avfilter.lib`, teria que nomear todas manualmente na importação?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu acho que do jeito que você mostrou na pergunta é o jeito "certo".

Mas também acho que dá pra fazer do jeito que você quer:

```
...
link_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../lib/ffmpeg/lib")
include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../lib/ffmpeg/include")
...
add_executable(appffmpeg)
target_link_libraries(appffmpeg curl avcodec avformat avutil)
```

Ref.
[link_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/link_directories.html)
[target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/target_link_libraries.html#command:target_link_libraries)

Obs. não testado.